# UiScrollable scrollIntoView stops just before scrolling into view

Tags: android, scroll, automated-tests, android-uiautomator

I have created the following wrap of `UiScrollable` for android testing:

```
protected fun UiScrollable.ensureScrolledIntoView(elementToScrollTo: UiObject) {
    val elementPresent = scrollIntoView(elementToScrollTo)
    if (!elementPresent) {
        Assert.fail("Expected element ${elementToScrollTo.selector} not found in scroll view")
    }
}
```

I believe the wrapper itself is not the problem, but sometimes the `scrollIntoView` fails to make the last needed scroll swipe. Best is to demonstrate with example:

[image: Illustration example]

Gives the error:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Expected element
>   UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.LinearLayout, DESCRIPTION=May,
>   CHILD=UiSelector[TEXT=7,
>   RESOURCE_ID=com.maypackage.android:id/calendar_day_text_view]] not
>   found in scroll view

And it was, obviously tasked to scroll to May 7th.

The same thing sometimes happens when I search for a date that will be found with up scroll: the method returns just one scroll short and the element is not found.

Has anyone encountered such problem? How to overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

After much more experimentation I found out the issue to be elements on the screen consuming certain scrolling attempts. This is most easily experienced in case of floating buttons, but the situation of the question shows more obscure example of the same. In most cases it turned out that [`setSwipeDeadZonePercentage`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiScrollable#setswipedeadzonepercentage) on the `UiScrollable` did the trick for me. This methods tells the scrollable that there is certain area in which no swiping attempts should be made. This solved the issues in cases of overflow buttons. For the more obscure cases I use the method below, which is still not guaranteed to work all the time, but is stable in my cases.

OLD, original answer:

Eventually, after much trials I found out that the framework error is more generic and does not necessary trigger a stop one swipe before the element is in the view. Frankly, I believe the problem is with the unstable behavior of `scrollForward` method which is used internally in the `scrollIntoView` method. Eventually I re-wrote my method as follows:

```
protected fun UiScrollable.ensureScrolledIntoView(elementToScrollTo: UiObject) {
    // this method used to use scrollIntoView, but it proved unstable
    if (elementToScrollTo.exists()) return
    while (scrollBackward()) {
        // no body needed
    }

    // very complex construct, because scroll forward seems to return false on first call
    var consecutiveFailingScrolls = 0
    while (consecutiveFailingScrolls < 2) {
        if (elementToScrollTo.exists()) return
        if (!scrollForward()) {
            consecutiveFailingScrolls++
        } else {
            consecutiveFailingScrolls = 0
        }
    }
    Assert.fail("Expected element ${elementToScrollTo.selector} not found in scroll view")
}
```

This is basically trying to address the framework instability and, up to the moment it has not failed me. By the way, I suspect the instability of `scrollIntoView` manifests only when we are scrolling lazily loading components like recycler views. For the moment I intend to continue using the library methods for non-lazy loading lists and see if more errors are encountered.